# Need help graphing the x axis of a sinusoid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

'Im trying to graph a simple sine wave, and I know how, I just keep getting the wrong x axis values. The signal has a frequency of 1000 Hz, so I should be seeing 1000 cycles per second, but that's not the case and Im not sure how to make it work. Here's what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = 1000
A = 5
t = np.linspace (0,100,100)
w = 2 * np.pi * f

signal = A * np.sin (w*t)

plt.figure ()
plt.plot (t,signal)
plt.show()
```

It doesn't show the correct number of cycles, considering the x axis is in seconds. How can I properly show the right number of cycles per second given 1000 Hz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is just the scaling of your time axis. `t = np.linspace (0,100,100)` gives you a 100-element array ranging from 0-100 (see [the doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)), so that's not an ideal resolution to plot 1 kHz data. It works fine if you chose another range and resolution for time:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = 1000
A = 5
t = np.linspace(0, 0.01, num=1000) # unit of t is seconds
w = 2 * np.pi * f
signal = A * np.sin(w*t)

plt.plot(t, signal)
plt.xlabel('time[s]')
plt.ylabel('amplitude')
plt.show()
```

gives me
[image: sine_plot]
... that's 10 cycles in 0.01 s == 1 kHz.